# Python classification: feature importance by class

Tags: python, data-science, classification

There are multiple ways to calculate the importance of every feature in a dataset. For instance, LogisticRegression from sklearn, or LGBMClassifier from lightgbm. The question is: is there a way to calculate feature importance for a dataset by class?

Assume I have a dataset that describes data of two classes. I need to find out which features are more significant for each of the classes.

Thank you for your time

Comment: As I know, Feature importance is a measurement of telling how powerful is the feature in predicting the target. In a classification problem, To calculate this we have to use data belongs to the target class and the other classes too. Just think that we first filter the data belongs to one class. Then what is there to predict. A feature affects not only the probability of belonging to a class. but also belonging to other class/es.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean the feature importance based on a machine learning model or not, but SHAP values provide insights into the feature importance based on a machine learning model. The documentation can be found at: https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
Basically what the SHAP values provide are: how much impact does a feature have on your prediction, and what kind (negative/positive) effect does it have.